# Tablas Personas y Direcciones

Tags: c#, mvc

Tengo dos Tablas una Personas y otra Direcciones, una persona puede tener muchas direcciones pero una dirección solo una persona. necesito crear una vista donde aparezcan todos los datos de las dos tablas, cada persona con sus respectivas direcciones, no se por donde empezar, tengo creado los modelos de Persona y Direccion.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas sobre cómo elaborar una buena pregunta.

Comment: Que has consultado?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo tienes las tablas en la db definidas como ser

```
Personas (tabla)
Id   PK
Nombre

Direcciones (tabla)
Id    PK
PersonaId   FK
Direccion
Numero
```

Para unirlo en una vista se usa el `INNER JOIN` o `LEFT JOIN` si es que quieres per a las personas que no tienen direccion asignada, entonces harias

```
SELECT p.Nombre, d.Direccion, d.Numero
 FROM Personas p 
 LEFT JOIN Direccionas d ON p.Id = d.PersonaId
```

asi relacionas las tablas por la columna que los vincula, puediendo mostrar datos de ambas